# Core Data complicated relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I have the following entities:

- Group
- Sector
- Data

Note:

- each Group can have one or more Sectors
- each Group can have one or more Data.  Each Sector within a Group can either have all or any of the Data that its Group has (by default, each Sector will have all the Data in its Group; then each Sector is capable of untagging any Data that it does not need)
- each Sector can be associated with none, one or more Sectors within its Group

How should I design the relationship?

Comment: Answered by Kyle W. below.  Thanks to Kyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a primary key and I don't think you're dealing with very complicated relationships here. There's a chance "GroupSector" and "SectorData" may be needed, but you may also be able fine with something simple like this.

[image]

- Group has many sectors; "one or more" is implied with this type of relationship.
- Group has many Data.
- Data has one Group.
- Sector has many (or can belong to many) groups. Your wording of "each Sector can be part of only one Group or can also be part of another Group" is confusing, but seems to imply a "to many" relationship with Group.

> Each Sector within a Group can either have all or any of the Data that its Group has (by default, each Sector will have all the Data in its Group; then each Sector is capable of untagging any Data that it does not need)

With this model, a Sector can retrieve the related data from the Group it belongs to. Any data that Group has, Sector can easily get to. That said, a sector may not want all of the Group data, which is what the "untaggedData" attribute is for. That attribute can hold a reference to any data that should be untagged for the sector. A Group with that Sector may not even have that data, but if it does, it will be "untagged." I'm not entirely sure if that's what you wanted here, so clarify if necessary.

> Each Sector can be associated with none, one or more Sectors within its Group.

With this model, you should be able to easily determine which Sectors belong to a specific group. You could also give Sector another "to many" relationship with itself, which would look like this:

[image]

**Update**

Per your comment:

> but what should be the attribute type for "untaggedData"

That depends. It could be a simple NSString with a collection of comma delimited Data attributes like name (e.g. @"data name 1 , data name 2, ..." assuming Data has a name attribute that doesn't change). That said, if the attribute you're referencing in Data is likely to change, this is NOT a good path to go down and you'll want to try a different data model.

The solution might be to get rid of the "untaggedData" attribute and use another entity called SectorData. This entity would have a "to one" relationship with Sector and "to many" relationship with Data. It should also have an inverse relationship with the new sectorData relationship in Sector and sectorData in Data. There may be a way to condense all this, but try it out as is and let me know how you fare. Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Kyle.  It's exactly what I need to start.  I will begin from here, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help point you in the right direction. Don't forget to accept my solution if it answered your question ;)

Comment: sorry Kyle, but what should be the attribute type for "untaggedData"?

Answer (score 1):

you dont need a primary key,
core data is not a relational db

to make a relationship between 2 entities, on graphical mode on your *.xcdatamodel

click on an entity with ctrl [the pointer will become a +], then drag the generated line to the other entity, make it one to one or one to many

Comment: i'm not sure for anyone with such high reputation will say RTFM... i am a newbie and just learned using core data.  i already know how to create entities and add relationship... this is basic and i already created an app using this... however if you read carefully my question, i am more of concerned on the complexity of relationship between Sector and Data... as I am more of a SQL db user, the scenario I show is complicated for me... good for you that you know everything, i just hope i'll find the answer soon... thanks anyways

Comment: hi, ok, now is more clear, make a screenshot of your db diagram, rephrase your question so we can help you better